# What does the term “trial card” mean in the field of engineering?

Tags: terminology

I heard this term from a colleague, however I wasn’t sure what it really meant.

Comment: I don’t think it’s a standard or common engineering term.

Comment: Please add more detail. What was the scenario in which this term was used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it truly applies to Engineering.  But I have seen it as a ship moves through the commissioning process, especially military.  Deficiencies during testing are documented so they can be fixed.

Commissioning process:

- Factory Acceptance Tests/Trials (FAT)
- Shipboard Tests
- Harbour Acceptance Tests (HAT)
- Sea Acceptance Tests (SAT)

From [SUPSHIP Operations Manual (SOM) - Chapter 10 – Testing, Trials and Delivery](https://www.navsea.navy.mil/Portals/103/Documents/SUPSHIP/SOM/Ch10-TestTrialsAndDelivery-01Nov17.pdf?ver=2019-03-22-120308-147#page=24)

> Electronic Trial Cards will be utilized to document known noncompliant discrepancies, including items identified in outstanding Quality Deficiency
> Reports/Corrective Action Reports. Deficiencies disclosed during all trials will be documented on Electronic Trial Cards and the status maintained in the management data base.

Answer (score 0):

It could mean someone is employed with a "trial period" stated on their contact - if they work out they continue, if not they leave at the end of the given period.

Can work well for either side in some situations.